# Solving for unknown functions

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, integral-equations

I am not a mathematician, so excuse if my question is silly or badly stated. I have the following problem. I have 2 conditions on two unknown continuously differentiable functions:

$$A(t)=\frac{1}{B(t)}+C
\\
B(t)=D-A(t)-\int_0^t A(\tau) d\tau.$$

C and D are constants. I also know $A(0)$ and $B(0)$. I am looking for a way to get the value of $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ for small $t>0$. So far I have a numerical solution, but that involves a lot of interpolation and I don't think it is very good.

I was wondering if there is some way to get an analytic solution for this problem. I don't expect you to solve the problem for me, I'm willing to learn and I'd be very grateful if you could point me towards possible readings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Differentiate both equations, then mess with the variables, to get
$$
(B^2 - 1)B' + CB^2 + B = 0.
$$

This does not appear to have a solution in elementary functions, although Wolfram Alpha is telling me that for $k$ an arbitrary constant, one has
$$
k - x = \frac{B(x)}{C} - \log(B(x)) + \frac{C^2 - 1}{C}\log(CB(x) + 1),
$$
which you can easily check (if it's true! - I haven't checked yet).

From this you can approximate $B$ (and hence $A$) as well as you can like.

Comment: It might be easier to just substitute the value of$A(t)$ from the first formula into the second formula, and then differentiate to get the DE.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED: Let's write everything in function of $E(t):=A(t)-C$ :

$$B(t)=\frac 1{E(t)}$$ $$\frac 1{E(t)}+E(t)=D-C-\int_0^t E(t)+C\ dt$$

after derivation the second equation becomes :
$$E'(t)\left(1-\frac 1{E(t)^2}\right)=-E(t)-C$$

$$\frac {E'(t)}{E(t)+C}-\frac {E'(t)}{(E(t)+C)E(t)^2}=-1$$

$$\frac {E'(t)}{E(t)+C}-\frac {E'(t)}{C^2}\left(\frac {1}{E(t)+C}-\frac {E(t)-C}{E(t)^2}\right)=-1$$
$$\frac {E'(t)}{E(t)+C}-\frac {E'(t)}{C^2}\left(\frac {1}{E(t)+C}-\frac 1{E(t)}+\frac C{E(t)^2}\right)=-1$$

Integrating this we get :
$$\log(E(t)+C)-\frac 1{C^2}\log(E(t)+C)+\frac 1{C^2}\log(E(t))+
\frac 1{CE(t)}=-t+F$$

that we may rewrite as (changing sign) :
$$t-F=\frac {1-C^2}{C^2}\log(E(t)+C)-\frac 1{C^2}\log(E(t))-
\frac 1{CE(t)}$$

with $F$ a constant and $E(t)=A(t)-C$

This is the same result as countinghaus' except that I expressed $t$ in function of $E(t)=A(t)-C$ while his result was in function of $B(t)=\dfrac 1{E(t)}$. Let's rewrite our result with $B(t)$ :
$$t-F=\frac {1-C^2}{C^2}\log\left(\frac 1{B(t)}+C\right)+\frac 1{C^2}\log(B(t))-
\frac {B(t)}C$$
$$\boxed{\displaystyle t=-
\frac {B(t)}C-\frac {C^2-1}{C^2}\log(1+C B(t))+\log(B(t))+F}$$

Obtaining $A(t)$ (or $B(t)$) in function of $t$ in 'closed form' is probably not possible except for specific values of ($C$) :

- $C=1$ : solutions $B(t)=-1$ and $\displaystyle B(t)=-W\left(-e^{F-t}\right)$
- $C=-1$ : solutions $B(t)=1$ and $\displaystyle B(t)=W\left(e^{F-t}\right)$
- $C=0$ : solutions $\displaystyle B(t)=\pm\frac {\sqrt{W\left(-e^{F-2t}\right)}}i$
  (with $W$ the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and $F$ a constant ; you may search other solutions using [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%27%2a%28x%5E2-1%29%2bx%5E3%2b1%2ax%5E2=0,%20x) by changing the ($C=1$ in the example) constant before $x^2$ in the query and get the plot of the result)